# Why others routers than default also applies routerLinkActive css class to them? Angular

Tags: css, angular

I want to do router module with default route "/" as below:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: HomeComponent},
    { path: 'messages', component: MessagesComponent },
    { path: 'profile', component: ProfileComponent },
]
```

And I am trying apply css class to elements as below:

```
    <a routerLink="/" routerLinkActive="activeLink">
        <span>Home</span>
    </a>

    <a class="messages" routerLink="/messages" routerLinkActive="activeLink">
        <span>Messages</span>
    </a>

    <a class="profile" routerLink="/profile" routerLinkActive="activeLink">
        <span>Profile</span>
    </a>
```

But when I try use routerLinkActive also other pages for example "/messages" and "/profile" take css class to and asign them. Why it take place here? What can I do to make this code correct?

Comment: Try to use `[routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}"` on your `<a>` tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you need to add `[routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}"`

Ref: https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLinkActive